# Mechanics associated with Headshots in WW2?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

It seems obvious that headshots do more damage, but I'm beginning to question that since quite often I come into two scenarios (*I believe this was with the type-100 but I don't remember exact specifics*).

- 4 shots to kill. All 4 landing on the upper body.
- 4 shots to kill. 2 shots to the head, 2 shots to the upper body.

Given this, it makes me question whether headshots actually do increased damage or if they're just there to boast your accuracy/skill.

Secondly, it only counts as a headshot if the killing shot hits the head correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every gun has a different damage stats so they do different amounts of damage and may take more bullets to kill someone.

For instance each sniper has different stats; some can one shot most of you, some can only one shot the head. That implies head shots do more damage. And yes a head shot only counts when hitting the head. Read the description below snipers as an example. Lee Enfield: "...one shot kill to torso and above".

Perusing a few [forums](https://community.callofduty.com/t5/World-War-II-General-Discussion/Headshot-multiplier/td-p/10502732) and speculation, they say the multiplier used to be 1.5x but now it's 1.1x;

You can see a list of guns and their [stats here.](https://www.dexerto.com/news/guide-every-weapon-in-call-of-duty-wwii/38177)